# Monks know how to drive a car?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-fist

In *The Iron Fist* S1 All Danny mentions about any transportation in Kun' Lun is carts, (donkey carts or whatever), However note that when he and Davos arrive at The Hand's compound to kill Bakuto, Danny mentions that he didn't let Davos drive as he did not have a license.

All I ask is how Davos or even Danny know how to drive a car, provided they are brought up in a monastery in another dimension and Danny was too young to learn driving at the time of crash.

Answer (score 5):

## Danny Rand learned how to drive **before** the crash.

He says in Episode 1 when he accosts Ward.

> I, uh haven't driven since my dad put me on his lap and let me drive around our place in the Hamptons.

Granted he won't have a licence (nor does Davos) but he knows enough to pilot a car (at least the basics).

Comment: Well I guess I have been meaning to ask that how Davos knows car driving....!!